# bash calculation using bc, and round up floating point

Tags: bash, shell

Sorry for my bad title. I'm so confuse to explain the title in 1 line.
this is my problem:

```
echo "scale=0;9 * 150 + 8.092 * 560 + 3.181" | bc
```

instead of getting

> 5885

but, i got output

> 5884.701

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know only division is using the information given by `scale`.

```
echo "scale=0; (9 * 150 + 8.092 * 560 + 3.181)/1" | bc
```

will echo 5884 since the integer part (quotient!) was taken only. To get your desired result (round) you might use:

```
echo "scale=0; ((9 * 150 + 8.092 * 560 + 3.181)+0.5)/1" | bc
```

note that this approach will not work for negative numbers! See this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89843

Comment: Not quite, though; you don't want to add 1 if the expression happens to be an exact integer. (Granted, the odds of that happening are very low for an arbitrary floating-point expression.)

Answer (score 0):

That's the right result. The man page of bc explains how scale widening applies here:

Since you multiply/add multiple numbers with a given scale, the result will have a different scale.